# How to dynamicly access a object and then edit its content

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm, object

So i have for example such an object:

```
let htmlDom = [
  {
    type: "div",
    att: {
      class: ["test", "test2"],
      id: "yoyo",
      "data-hello": ["jan", "john"],
    },
    content: "Hello",
    child: [
      {
        type: "div",
        content: "test",
        child: [{}],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

And now i want to dynamicly acess it, for example: htmlDom[0].child[0].child[0], and now the numbers of children can vary and the numbers generally. lets say for example i have an array of [0, 0, 0], How can i then acess that path dynamicly by using the numbers in the array, and then change the content of the last child[0]? The thing is that for example the array can later on vary to [0,2,4,3,6] and such, and depending on the array lenght i need to create more .child[]

Comment: You're basically asking for a recursion function to read or set children? What have you tried so far to solve this yourself?

Comment: Just make a loop from 1 to n-1 and access .child[index] leaving first index 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first grab the last index from your array of indexes using [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), and then use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on the now modified indexes array to iterate over your children arrays. By setting the accumulator as the starting `htmlDom` you can access the  objects  at each index and its child array for each iteration of `.reduce()`, where the `child` array from each object is returned. This child array is then used as the `acc` for the next call/iteration of your reduce method. Once you have found the last child array, you can use index which you previously popped off your array to set/update the value:

```js
let htmlDom = [ { type: "div", att: { class: ["test", "test2"], id: "yoyo", "data-hello": ["jan", "john"], }, content: "Hello", child: [ { type: "div", content: "test", child: [{}], }, ], }, ];

const changeByIdxs = (arr, [...idxs], value) => {
  const lastIdx = idxs.pop();
  const finalArr = idxs.reduce((acc, i) => acc[i].child, arr);
  finalArr[lastIdx] = value;
}

changeByIdxs(htmlDom, [0, 0, 0], {x: 1});
console.log(htmlDom);
```

The above can be implemented with for loops if you find that easier to understand:

```js
const htmlDom = [{ type: "div", att: { class: ["test", "test2"], id: "yoyo", "data-hello": ["jan", "john"], }, content: "Hello", child: [{ type: "div", content: "test", child: [{}], }, ], }, ];
const changeByIdxs = (arr, [...idxs], value) => {
  const lastIdx = idxs.pop();
  let finalArr = arr;
  for (let i = 0; i < idxs.length; i++) {
    const idx = idxs[i];
    finalArr = finalArr[idx].child;
  }
  finalArr[lastIdx] = value
}

changeByIdxs(htmlDom, [0, 0, 0], {x: 1});
console.log(htmlDom);
```

Comment: I dont understand it in an technical view, but can i buy you a coffee? :3 - _did go to research it_

Comment: @Autumnlight I've updated my answer to use a for loop instead of reduce, which you might find easier to understand

Comment: Thanks for this edit! Before i talked to someone who explained it me indepth, but now i know 2 ways to do it! You helped me alot, thanks sir!

Comment: I just wanted to thank you again, from that example I started to understand objects, and now I've become very well in js. Thank you. like really :3

Comment: @Autumnlight :-) glad it helped you out, happy for you!