# How to change a value of a nested property in an object dynamically

Tags: javascript

```js
const array_of_property_names = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

const nested_obj = {
  A: {
    B: {
      C: {
        D: 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the event that `array_of_property_names` is dynamic, how can we use it to modify `nested_obj`?

Comment: related: [Access a nested property with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066787/access-a-nested-property-with-a-string)

Comment: Are you after something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66598458/5648954)?